# VLOOKUP for OLAP Power Pivot

Tags: excel, olap, powerpivot

How Can I use lookup formula for OLAP Power Pivot?

When I typing:

```
=VLOOKUP(N4;Sheet1!traffic;2;FALSE) - traffic is a Power Pivot name
```

I get "#Name?" error, but when specify range of this Power Pivot table (without headers) it works.

I prefer to use Power Pivot name then range, because size will be changing.

Comment: You will have to use CUBESET function. Moreover you can also create DAX measure and show the values using a pivot table.

Comment: How can I use CUBESET function with VLOOKUP? Do you have any example?

Comment: Basically [CUBESET](https://www.powerpivotpro.com/2010/02/introducing-cubeset-and-cuberankedmember/) lets you connect to your PowerPivot model and get coumns or measure values.